# ReactJs, TypeScript TypeError: menuItems.map is not a function, error on map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hello I have the following logic of useState and map an array to display only one dropdownItems at a time

here i have my array with tags ( menu name, links ( to router), icon( menu icon), if have dropdown Items ( dropdown items))

**my MenuTags:**

```
export interface IDropdownItems {
  Name: string;
  Link: string;
}
export interface ITag {
  Name: string;
  Link: string;
  Icon: IconType;
  DropdownItems: IDropdownItems[] | null;
  Active: boolean;
}

export const SideBarTags: ITag[] = [
  {
    Name: 'Tutoriais',
    Link: '../tutorials',
    Icon: GoBook,
    DropdownItems: null,
    Active: false,
  },
  {
    Name: 'Avisos',
    Link: '../news',
    Icon: GoAlert,
    DropdownItems: null,
    Active: false,
  },
  {
    Name: 'Serviços',
    Link: '../services',
    Icon: GoRocket,
    Active: false,
    DropdownItems: [
      { Name: 'Elo Boost', Link: '/eloBost' },
      { Name: 'Duo Boost', Link: '/duoBoost' },
      { Name: 'MD10', Link: '/eloBost' },
      { Name: 'Coaching', Link: '/duoBoost' },
      { Name: 'Vitóriais', Link: '/duoBoost' },
    ],
  },
  {
    Name: 'Carteira',
    Link: '../cartcredit',
    Icon: FaCoins,
    Active: false,
    DropdownItems: [
      { Name: 'Histórico', Link: '/history' },
      { Name: 'Adicionar Crédito', Link: '/add' },
    ],
  },
];
```

**my MenuTag ( useState and map here ):**

```
const MenuTags: React.FC<MenuTags> = ({ sideisOpen }) => {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState(SideBarTags);
  return (
    <MenuList open={sideisOpen}>
      {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
        <MenuTagsItems
          key={item.Name}
          Name={item.Name}
          Active={item.Active}
          DropdownItems={item.DropdownItems}
          Icon={item.Icon}
          Link={item.Link}
          sideisOpened={sideisOpen}
          tagFunction={setMenuItems}
        />
      ))}
    </MenuList>
  );
};
```

my **MenuTagsItems**

```
const MenuTagsItems: React.FC<ITag & IMenuTagsItems> = ({
  sideisOpened,
  Name,
  Active,
  DropdownItems,
  Icon,
  Link,
  tagFunction,
}) => {
  const clickHandler = (value) => () => {
    console.log(value);
    tagFunction((items) =>
      items.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        Active: item.Name === value,
      }))
    );
  };
  return (
    <ListItem>
      <ListWrap
        open={sideisOpened}
        active={Active}
        onClick={() => {
          tagFunction(Name);
        }}
      >
        <a>
          <Icon size={18} />
          <span className="li-name">{Name}</span>
        </a>
      </ListWrap>
      {DropdownItems && (
        <Drop
          active={Active}
          dropItems={DropdownItems}
          Icon={Icon}
          isOpen={sideisOpened}
          setVisible={tagFunction}
        />
      )}
    </ListItem>
  );
};
```

and if menu tag have dropdown items 
**my DropDown:**

```
const Drop: React.FC<IDrop> = ({
  active,
  isOpen,
  dropItems,
  setVisible,
  Icon,
}) => {
  return (
    <OpenedStyled active={active}>
      {dropItems.map((item) => (
        <li className="li-open" key={item.Name}>
          <Icon />
          <a>{item.Name}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </OpenedStyled>
  );
};
```

sorry i forgot error

i got this error:
Uncaught TypeError: menuItems.map is not a function
here:

```
<MenuList open={sideisOpen}>
  {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
    <MenuTagsItems
      key={item.Name}
      Name={item.Name}
      Active={item.Active}
      DropdownItems={item.DropdownItems}
      Icon={item.Icon}
      Link={item.Link}
      sideisOpened={sideisOpen}
      tagFunction={setMenuItems}
    />
  ))}
</MenuList>
```

Comment: the title of your question would not help anybody who may experience the same problem. a more appropriate title may be to say what library you're using and which component you're having issue with. by doing so, you'll also help us provide the answer you're looking for as well.  i can tell you're not calling the "clickHandler" from the onClick event handler on "ListWrap" component. that would be the start of the issue you're having, but i really can't tell how the onClick event would pass the value the clickHandler is using to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem is here:

```
<ListWrap
    open={sideisOpened}
    active={Active}
    onClick={() => {
       tagFunction(Name);
    }}
>
```

More specific, you are calling `tagFunction` (which is `setMenuItems`) in `onClick` handler with a `Name` parameter that is not an array, and you are setting it for `menuItems` state. Since it's not an array it doesn't have map, so there is an error.

Similar potential error you might have here:

```
<Drop
   active={Active}
   dropItems={DropdownItems}
   Icon={Icon}
   isOpen={sideisOpened}
   setVisible={tagFunction}
/>
```

with `setVisible` param, but I see it's not used in a Component yet.

Comment: could you help me how i could solve or improve the code? I'm confused